# how do I use switch and case in a java game?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, slick2d

I'm making a game in `Slick2D` and I have a lot of 'if' statements and I want to get rid of that. Now this is my code:

```
if((playerPositionX>570 && playerPositionX<835) && (playerPositionY>16 && playerPositionY<260)){
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawString("Ready to play? press enter!", 400,350);
}
```

Everything is fine but I have like 8 and going up of these, obviously with different coordinates.
So I would like to know if it's possible to use a switch and case method to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a Switch with ranges as cases. In other words, something like this:

```
 Switch(playerPosition)
     case 570-835: 
     ....
```

doesn't exist. You could do:

```
int num;

if (playerPositionX>570 && playerPositionX<835){
    num = 0;
if (playerPositionX>836 && playerPositionX<1000){
    num = 1;
```

and then

```
 Switch(num){
     case 0: 
     ...
     case 1: 
     ...
```

but you'll still have to use the if statements.

Comment: Okay thanks drewmore, although I have to use if statements but, it's more organized, definitely will try it.